# i cut my iphone 4 jailbroken with evasi0n off and after i powered my phone back on i lost my apps. what can i do to get them back?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

note: it says that my storage is almost full, leading me to believe they are still there. just somewhere else, please help!

Also, I have tried looking at other people with similar or the same problems but I couldn't find anyone, this is very important to me for my phone is all I have left. please help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you had a tethered jailbreak. If this is so you will need to run it by your jailbreaking program again on your PC/Mac and then it should be working again.

This issue does not happen when you do untethered jailbreaks.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an untethered jailbreak especially since he knows that he used evasi0n.